# How can I access this keyword in Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a typescript class in my angular project like this:

```
export class CreateGeojsonLayerCommand implements Icommand {
    parameters: Object;

    execute(parameters: Object): Object {
        this.parameters = parameters;

        let layer = new Vector({            
            style:  createStyleFunction
        });
    }

    private createStyleFunction(feature: any): Style {
        //this.parameters is undefined here

    }
}
```

The `new Vector` object is a third party tool object. So I have create the `createStyleFunction` out of the `execute` method. But I can not access `parameters` variable using this keyword like `this.parameters`.

Comment: this seems to be a scope probleme. you should use an arrow function like this "style: () => { this.createStyleFunction(); }"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an arrow function, otherwise this refers to the particular context,

```
private createStyleFunction = (feature: any): Style => {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `execute` function gets called before you use `createStyleFunction` otherwise `parameters` will not have been instantiated. Or add a constructor to the class to instantiate `parameters`.